# C# Entity Framework Pagination Children Includes

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, entity

I am looking for the fastest way to do the following operation. What I need to accomplish, is I have a screen that displays the "Parts" that are defined inside of a "Lot". Each part has objects of a station, and each station has objects of tools, and each tool can have measurements.

My problem is I cannot get the pagination to work. The incoming offset is 0, and the number of records to take is 20 however the following operation is not working:

`Lot foundLot = EntitiesContext.Lots.Where(x => x.ID == lotID)
    .IncludeFilter(lot => lot.Parts.OrderBy(n => n.PartID).Skip(offset).Take(numberOfRecords).ToList())
    .IncludeOptimized(lot => lot.Parts.Select(parts => parts.Stations))
    .IncludeOptimized(lot => lot.Parts.Select(parts => parts.Stations.Select(station => station.Tools)))
    .IncludeOptimized(lot => lot.Parts.Select(parts => parts.Stations.Select(station => 
       station.Tools.Select(tools => tools.Measurements))))
    .FirstOrDefault();`

So I am trying to filter to only grab certain parts, and then of those filtered parts, I want to grab all of the children's data associated with them. I have checked all of the existing stack overflow articles related to this, and the changes I make either result in the Z.EntityFrameworkPlus package throwing a generic exception, that provides no details (which is what the above code does), or if I use the regular EntityFramework functions it throws an exception for the invalid path.

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after reading the docs for Z.EntityFrameworkPlus I now see you cannot use IncludeFilter and IncludeOptimzed on the same LINQ statement

https://entityframework-plus.net/query-include-optimized

I switched IncludeFilter to IncludeOptimzed and it works.